# powershell | csv file edit each line in Colum A to set maximum characters

Tags: powershell, csv, substring

```
$lower = Import-Csv "C:\\Users\\X\\Desktop\\U\\cvv.csv"  
$lower | ForEach-Object {

       src['A']=src['A'].str[:20].str.lower()
    
     } 

$lower |
Export-Csv -Path "C:\\Users\\X\\Desktop\\U\\cvv2.csv"
```

I tried this method, but it does not work.

I want that if it is over 20 characters to delete and match it to a maximum of 20.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're mixing Python and PowerShell syntax.

You're probably looking for this:

```bash
$lower = Import-Csv 'C:\Users\X\Desktop\U\cvv.csv'
$lower | ForEach-Object {
  $_.A = $_.A.Substring(0, 20).ToLower() 
}
# ... Export-Csv command omitted.
```

However, if there's a chance that some property values have *fewer* than 20 characters, more work is needed, namely to avoid the exception that the `.Substring()` method would otherwise throw.

```bash
$lower = Import-Csv 'C:\Users\X\Desktop\U\cvv.csv'
$lower | ForEach-Object {
  $val = if ($_.A.Length -gt 20) { $_.A.Substring(0, 20) } else { $_.A }
  $_.A = $val.ToLower() 
}
```

- The following is a shorter alternative, but will perform poorly if *many* of the input strings are shorter than 20 characters, because exception handling is expensive in terms of performance:

  - `try { $_.A.Substring(0, 20) } catch { $_.A }`
- In *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, you can shorten the `if` statement to:

  - `$_.A.Length -gt 20 ? $_.A.Substring(0, 20) : $_.A`

---

##### Optional reading: comparing the performance of various substring-extraction approaches.

- There are several approaches to extracting substrings in PowerShell, and they vary widely with respect to verbosity and performance:

  - The two aspects aren't related, however, and, in fact, the most verbose approach is fastest in this case.
  - Broadly speaking, the approaches can be classified as:

    - Use of the .NET `.Substring()` method
    - Use of *array slicing*, i.e. treating a string as a character array to extract a sub-array from and
    - Use of [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) operations via the [`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator)
- Below are the results of benchmarks, which give a *rough* sense of *relative* performance:

  - Performance measurements in PowerShell aren't an exact science, and the results depend on many factors - not least the host hardware; the benchmarks below average 50 runs to get a better sense, and it is the *relative* performance, reflected in the `Factor` column that is of interest (`1.00` reflecting the fastest time, all other values being multiples of that).
  - Substring extraction of (up to) 20 chars. is performed on `1,000` strings, half of which are longer than that, half of which are shorter.
- **Important**: The benchmarks juxtapose *conditional* solutions  for `.Substring()` calls with *unconditional* `-replace` and array-slicing solutions, which skews the results - to compare true substring-extraction performance, the latter two approaches need to be modified to use conditionals too.

  - The reason for using conditional processing only for the `.Substring()` approach is that it is a *necessity* there - in order to avoid exceptions - whereas the appeal of the other approaches is *concision*, i.e. *not* having to use conditionals.

**Benchmark results**:

- Results from running in *Windows PowerShell* v5.1 on a Windows 10 machine:

```
Factor Secs (50-run avg.) Command
------ ------------------ -------
1.00   0.001              # .Substring + if...
1.71   0.002              # .Substring + [math]::Min()...
5.24   0.006              # -replace + capture group...
8.32   0.010              # -replace + lookbehind...
160.84 0.198              # .Substring + try...
229.07 0.281              # array slicing + [string]::new()...
294.62 0.362              # array slicing + -join ...
```

- Results from running in *PowerShell (Core)* 7.3.0 on the same Windows 10 machine:

```
Factor Secs (50-run avg.) Command
------ ------------------ -------
1.00   0.002              # .Substring + ternary conditional…
1.09   0.002              # .Substring + if…
2.98   0.005              # .Substring + [math]::Min()…
3.79   0.006              # -replace + capture group…
6.64   0.011              # -replace + lookbehind…
132.11 0.215              # array slicing + [string]::new()…
160.99 0.262              # array slicing + -join …
163.68 0.266              # .Substring + try…
```

- **Summary**:

  - The `.Substring()`-based approaches are by far the fastest - except if combined with `try` / `catch` (exception handling is expensive).

    - The v7+ ternary conditional (`? :`) performs about the same as the equivalent `if` statement.
  - The `-replace`-based solutions are slower by a factor of 3-5 with the capture-group variant, and about twice as slow as that with the variant that uses a look-behind assertion.
  - By far the slowest are the array-slicing approaches and the solution involving `try` / `catch`, by two orders of magnitude.

**Benchmark source code**:

- To run these benchmarks yourself, you must download function `Time-Command` from [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/9e1f13978620b09ab2d15da5535d1b27).

  - Assuming you have looked at the linked Gist's source code to ensure that it is safe (which I can personally assure you of, but you should always check), you can install it directly as follows:

    ```bash
    irm https://gist.github.com/mklement0/9e1f13978620b09ab2d15da5535d1b27/raw/Time-Command.ps1 | iex
    ```

```bash
# Create 1000 strings, half of which longer than 20 chars., and half shorter.
$strs = , ('x' * 30) * 500 + , ('y' * 10) * 500

# Construct an array of script blocks with the various
# substring-extraction methods.
$cmds = 
{ # -replace + capture group
  foreach ($s in $strs) {
    $s -replace '^(.{20}).+', '$1'
  }
}, 
{ # -replace + lookbehind
  foreach ($s in $strs) {
    $s -replace '(?<=^.{20}).+'
  }
},
{ # .Substring + try
  foreach ($s in $strs) {
    try { $s.Substring(0, 20) } catch { $_}
  }
},
{ # .Substring + if
  foreach ($s in $strs) {
    if ($s.Length -gt 20) { $s.Substring(0, 20) } else { $s }
  }
},
{ # .Substring + [math]::Min()
  foreach ($s in $strs) {
    $s.Substring(0, [Math]::Min($s.Length, 20))
  }
},
{ # array slicing + -join 
  foreach ($s in $strs) {
    -join $s[0..19]
  }
},
{ # array slicing + [string]::new()
  foreach ($s in $strs) {
    [string]::new($s[0..19])
  }
}

# PowerShell (Core): add variant with ternary conditional.
if ($IsCoreClr) {
  # Note: The script block must be constructed *as a string*,
  #       to avoid breaking the parsing stage of the script in Windows PowerShell.
  $cmds += [scriptblock]::Create(@'
  # .Substring + ternary conditional
  foreach ($s in $strs) {
    $s.Length -gt 20 ? $s.Substring(0, 20) : $s
  }  
'@)
}

# Compare the performance of various substring extraction methods,
# averaged over 50 runs.
Time-Command -Count 50 $cmds
```

Comment: Or with -replace: `$_.A -replace '^(.{20}).*', '$1'`

Comment: Thanks, @Theo. Using `.+` instead of `.*` is a slight optimization. I code-golfed and tried `-replace '(?<=^.{20}).+'`, but more concise isn't necessarily faster, as I've learned: please see my update, which contrasts the performance of the various approaches.

Comment: Wow! I never even considered how fast it would be as compared to the `.Substring()` method, It was just a way of getting a max length without having to deal with an exception if the string is shorter than the required maximum length. Really appreciate the benchmarking you did here!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Theo. Pragmatically speaking, given the results, `-replace '^(.{20}).+', '$1'` is probably fine in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use the [index operator `[ ]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#index-operator--) in combination with the [range operator `..`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#range-operator-):

```sh
Import-Csv "C:\\Users\\X\\Desktop\\U\\cvv.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    $_.A = [string]::new($_.A[0..19]).ToLower() # Update the the `A` value
    $_ # Output the object
} | Export-Csv -Path "C:\\Users\\X\\Desktop\\U\\cvv2.csv"
```

It would handle strings that are below or above the desired Length:

```
PS /> 'HELLO WORLD', 'ONLY 20 CHARS LENGTH ALLOWED' | ForEach-Object {
    [string]::new($_[0..19]).ToLower()
}


hello world
only 20 chars length
```

Comment: That is probably the closest equivalent to the OP's own approach, but the array slicing is expensive (though it may not matter in practice). I got curious and decided to compare the performance of various substring-extraction approaches, and the results are interesting: please see the bottom section of my answer.

Comment: Nice finding @mklement0. I didn't put performance in consideration in my answer just simplicity hence why no `if` and `continue`. It's also worth noting that hitting a `catch` block is also quite expensive. Array slicing is a bit expensive yes, but it's the `if` statement the one that is super efficient (this is what I see adding an `if` to the slicing techniques and increasing the dataset to 20k elements https://imgur.com/a/1gnMhKF)

Comment: All that said, +1 for the faithful translation of the OP's code, and, from the perspective of _concision_, it is an interesting solution.

Comment: P.S.: The reason I didn't combine `if` with the array-slicing and `-replace` operations is that I thought of the `if` as solely necessary to avoid the `.Substring()` exceptions, but you're right that that skews the benchmarks. With `if` applied to all approaches, the impact of the specific substring-extraction approach becomes clearer, as your screenshot (which I only saw just now) indicates. Out of curiosity: what tool did you use there?

Comment: @mklement0 it is unfortunate that Python's _string slicing_ is not a thing in PowerShell, we are forced to `.ToCharArray()` into indexing here :( the module is called [Benchpress](https://github.com/StartAutomating/Benchpress/)

Comment: not works .....