# is there a way to check if a program is installed just by filename in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a powershell script to auto install all .msi and .exe files silently in a directory. However while doing this i want to check if any of the programs are already installed.

I know i can get all installed files in the system like below

```
$32bit_softwares = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |
                        Select-Object DisplayName,DisplayVersion,Publisher,InstallDate
                        
$64bit_softwares = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |
                        Select-Object DisplayName,DisplayVersion,Publisher,InstallDate
$all_softwares = $32bit_softwares+$64bit_softwares
```

and i can get the filenames of the files in the directory like below:

```
$directoryRead = Read-Host -Prompt "enter directory"
$fileNames = Get-ChildItem $directory -Recurse -include *.exe,*.msi | ForEach-Object {$_.name}
```

How can i compare these 2 in a loop? like

```
$all_softwares.DisplayName -like "$softwareName*"
```

I am not sure a like filter above will do the job as filenames will be like examplename.exe

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem that I see and I think you are asking about is that the installer filename will be different than the software name you pull out of the Registry. With the difference it will be hard to match up exactly.

Is the set of MSI's and/or EXE's (the installers) a known, static set? Would it be possible to setup a hash table (dictionary) mapping between the Registry name and the installer name?

This would make matching exactly while looping through the installers and doing a `.Contains` on the array from the Registry easier.

Comment: yes, it is about names, they may not be static, should i try to compare first "x" letters of the .name to .Displayname? is it possible to truncate the name in powershell?

Comment: This is off-the-wall thinking but will each MSI/EXE be from a unique vendor?  You could try reading the installer's Properties and look at the Copyright field and remove the Copyright text leaving what should be the vendor name.  Then compare that to the Publisher field from your Registry query.  You would still have to apply some logic to get these to match up.

Comment: If you do want to try taking the first n characters of the name, please see this post for examples of using PowerShell's `.Substring` to pull out parts of a string. Eduard Uta on this post has a great example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27944302/substring-in-powershell-to-truncate-string-length